# Stackoverflow events notifications does not work (or work weird) in IE10 (Windows 7)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-interface, notification-bar, internet-explorer-10

Actually, besides of actually the question itself, I've got also a question whether should I post such things in here or there is some other specific place for it.

The problem:

When I use stackoverflow via IE10 on Windows 7, there is no notifications (top left corner) appear (i.e., not always). I often need the page to reload to see them.

Comment: Can't repro. Take a look at the console in the developer tools (F12), if you see a `WebSocket opened` message, it is working.

Comment: Well, that's a bit tricky, because sometimes it works. But for me more often rather not. (Just saw also the same with rating update - it updated only after the page reload).

Comment: I know what I am talking about, because never experienced (at least, never noticed) that when worked with Chrome before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking as no-repro -- there were some issues at the time with our push system, but it seems pretty stable now. If you can reliably reproduce, open a new bug with details.

Comment: Well, it's been a year since that question. I am sure, the thing with IE10 must go away in any case by this time (and further). :)